# Output summarise value with Angular.JS and ng-table

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ngtable

I got the JSON:

```
 var   scholars = [{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Unit":"PA","Institution":"University of Haifa","teken":1,"FirstYearActive":"2007","hIndex":"3","j2014":0,"j2013":4,"j2012":3,"j2011":0,"j2010":0,"j20052009":2,"j20002004":0,"j19901999":0,"jPriorto1990":0,"ab2014":0,"ab2013":0,"ab2012":0,"ab2011":0,"ab2010":0,"ab20052009":0,"ab20002004":0,"ab19902000":0,"abPriorto1990":0,"c2014":5,"c2013":10,"c2012":7,"c2011":0,"c2010":3,"c20052009":2,"c20002004":0,"c19901999":0,"cPriorto1990":0,"b2014":0,"b2013":0,"b2012":0,"b2011":0,"b2010":0,"b20052009":0,"b20002004":0,"b19902000":0,"bPriorto1990":0,"YearsActive":"8","HIE":"72.9"},
{"FirstName":"John","LastNAme":"Smith","Unit":"G&PT","Institution":"University of Haifa","teken":1,"FirstYearActive":"1996","hIndex":"3","j2014":0,"j2013":0,"j2012":0,"j2011":0,"j2010":0,"j20052009":1,"j20002004":2,"j19901999":2,"jPriorto1990":0,"ab2014":0,"ab2013":0,"ab2012":0,"ab2011":0,"ab2010":0,"ab20052009":0,"ab20002004":0,"ab19902000":0,"abPriorto1990":0,"c2014":3,"c2013":1,"c2012":3,"c2011":5,"c2010":3,"c20052009":2,"c20002004":0,"c19901999":0,"cPriorto1990":0,"b2014":0,"b2013":0,"b2012":0,"b2011":0,"b2010":0,"b20052009":0,"b20002004":0,"b19902000":0,"bPriorto1990":0,"YearsActive":"19","HIE":"25.5"},
{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Guitar","Unit":"IR","Institution":"University of Haifa","teken":1,"FirstYearActive":"2009","hIndex":"0","j2014":0,"j2013":0,"j2012":0,"j2011":0,"j2010":0,"j20052009":1,"j20002004":0,"j19901999":0,"jPriorto1990":0,"ab2014":0,"ab2013":0,"ab2012":0,"ab2011":0,"ab2010":0,"ab20052009":0,"ab20002004":0,"ab19902000":0,"abPriorto1990":0,"c2014":0,"c2013":0,"c2012":0,"c2011":0,"c2010":0,"c20052009":0,"c20002004":0,"c19901999":0,"cPriorto1990":0,"b2014":0,"b2013":0,"b2012":0,"b2011":0,"b2010":0,"b20052009":0,"b20002004":0,"b19902000":0,"bPriorto1990":0,"YearsActive":"6","HIE":"0"}]
```

And I need to summarise all of the **j2014**'s with this code:

```
var j14sum = 0;
      for (var i in scholars){
        if (scholars[i].Institution == "University of Haifa")
          j14sum += parseInt(scholars[i].j2014);
      };
```

Now, how I make it work with angular.js and output the results with ng-table?

Many thanks!

Comment: You want to print the j14 sum for all different institution ?

Comment: Yes that what I want

Comment: And also for the rest of the "j"s (j2013, j2012...)

Comment: I didn't used ng-table but I have done something I hope that can help you  : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oFreq?editors=101              Ask me for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out how to solve the issue.

```
var reduced = scholars.reduce(function(map,obj){
    if(!(obj.Institution in map)){
        map[obj.Institution] = {
            Institution:obj.Institution,
            j2014: 0
        };
    }
    map[obj.Institution].j2014 += parseInt(obj.j2014);
    return map;
},{});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/axdg1r4t/4/